# Как сделать чтобы при выборе значения QCombobox, который создается в таблице QTableWidget без указания имени по итерации срабатывал метод

Tags: python, pyqt5, сигналы-слоты, qtablewidget, qcombobox

Я пытаюсь понять, как сделать так, чтобы при выборе `QCombobox`, который создается без явного указания имени по нажатию кнопки в таблице `QTableWidget` срабатывал какой-нибудь метод.

Внизу приведен пример создания таблицы с `QCombobox` в `QTableWidget`, по нажатию кнопки добавляются строки.

При выборе значения пользователем значения в `QCombobox`, хочу чтобы срабатывал метод `show_message()`, который показывает сообщение, какой `QCombobox` сработал и вывести его значение **`«Продано»`** или «**`В наличии»`** внутри сообщения, а так же знать в какой строке выбран `QCombobox`.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QMessageBox


class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
  def __init__(self, parent=None):
    super().__init__()
    self.centralWidget = QWidget()
    self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)
    self.row_count = 1
    self.table_index = 0

    self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget()
    self.tableWidget.setRowCount(0)
    self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(2)

    self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Добавить строки таблицы')
    self.button_1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Вывести значение ячейки')

    self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self.centralWidget)
    self.layout.addWidget(self.tableWidget)
    self.layout.addWidget(self.button)
    self.layout.addWidget(self.button_1)

    self.button.clicked.connect(self.add_cells)

    self.button_1.clicked.connect(self.show_message)

def add_cells(self):  # метод для добавления строки и ячеек
    self.tableWidget.setRowCount(self.row_count)
    self.tableWidget.setItem(self.table_index, 0,
                             QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem('Nokia'))

    combobox = QtWidgets.QComboBox()  # Создаю combobox
    combobox.addItem('Продано')
    combobox.addItem('В наличии')

    self.tableWidget.setCellWidget(self.table_index, 1, combobox)  # Добавляю строки по итерации
    self.row_count += 1
    self.table_index += 1

def show_message(self):
    msg = QMessageBox()
    msg.setWindowTitle('Выбран вариант Combobox')
    msg.setText('Вы выбрали значение "ТЕКСТ QCombobox (Продано или В наличии"')
    msg.setInformativeText('Вы выбрали QCombobox в строке "Номер строки"')
    msg.exec_()

if __name__ == '__main__':
   app = QApplication(sys.argv)
   w = MyWindow()
   w.show()
   sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Как обычно `comboBox.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.showMessage)`, или `currentTextChanged`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> void QComboBox::**textActivated**(const QString &text)
>
> Этот сигнал отправляется, когда пользователь выбирает элемент в поле со списком.
> Текст элемента передается. 
> Обратите внимание, что этот сигнал отправляется, даже если выбор не изменен.
> Если вам нужно знать, когда выбор действительно изменится,
> используйте сигнал `currentIndexChanged`() или `currentTextChanged`().
>
> **`Эта функция была введена в Qt 5.14.`**

Я не проверял логику вашего приложения, а добавил только сигнал и слот.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, \
    QVBoxLayout, QMessageBox


class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__()
        self.centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)
        self.row_count = 1
        self.table_index = 0

        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget()
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(0)
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(2)

        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Добавить строки таблицы')
        self.button_1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Вывести значение ячейки')

        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self.centralWidget)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.tableWidget)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.button)
#        self.layout.addWidget(self.button_1)

        self.button.clicked.connect(self.add_cells)
#        self.button_1.clicked.connect(self.show_message)

    def add_cells(self):  
        row = self.tableWidget.rowCount()                           # +++
        
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(self.row_count)
        self.tableWidget.setItem(
            self.table_index, 
            0,
            QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(f'Nokia {self.table_index}')
        )

        combobox = QtWidgets.QComboBox()  
        combobox.addItem('Продано')
        combobox.addItem('В наличии')
# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
        combobox.textActivated.connect(
            lambda text, row=row, cb=combobox : 
                   self.current_text(text, row, cb))
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        self.tableWidget.setCellWidget(self.table_index, 1, combobox)  
        self.row_count += 1
        self.table_index += 1
    
    '''
    def show_message(self):
        msg = QMessageBox()
        msg.setWindowTitle('Выбран вариант Combobox')
        msg.setText('Вы выбрали значение "ТЕКСТ QCombobox (Продано или В наличии"')
        msg.setInformativeText('Вы выбрали QCombobox в строке "Номер строки"')
        msg.exec_()
    '''

# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv       
    def current_text(self, text, row, cb):
        msg = QMessageBox()
        msg.setWindowTitle('Выбран вариант Combobox')
        msg.setText(f'Вы выбрали значение: {text}')
        msg.setInformativeText(f'Вы выбрали QCombobox в строке: {row}')
        msg.exec_()
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    

if __name__ == '__main__':
   app = QApplication(sys.argv)
   w = MyWindow()
   w.show()
   sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: вы просто мастер PyQt5. Спасибо за такой развернутый ответ, это ответ ответов! Люблю Вас!

Comment: @catharsis пожалуйста